# Show that element is in an interval

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions

In Spivaks Calculus in chapter 4, problem 2 states:

> There is a very useful way of describing the points of the closed interval $[a, b]$ where we assume that $a < b$.
>
> a) First consider the interval $[0, b]$, for $b > 0$. Prove that if $x$ is in $[0, b]$, then $x=tb$ for some $t$ with $0 \le t \le 1$. [...]
>
> b) Now prove that if $x$ is in $[a, b]$, then $x = (1-t)a + tb$ for some $t$ with $0 \le t \le 1$. [...]

So I think I understand where the question is going. I see two linear equations:

- For $[0, b]$ we have $f(t) = tb$
- For $[a, 0]$ we have $g(t) = (1-t)a$
- We can add those together: $g(t) + f(t) = (1-t)a + tb = a - at + tb = a + t(b - a)$ and arrive at another linear equation that describes the interval $[a, b]$ where $t$ is the slope.

Now the question for me is, on a technical level, what do I need to do to:

> prove that if $x$ is in $[a, b]$, then $x = (1-t)a + tb$ for some $t$ with $0 \le t \le 1$

How can I show that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can construct the $t$ explicitly.

Suppose $$x=(1-t)a + tb,$$

then we have

$$x=a+t(b-a)$$

Can you solve for $t$ explicitly in terms of $x, a, b$ and verify that $0 \le t \le 1$.

You can use similar strategy for part $a$ too.